# How do you install an external Java library such as caldav4j in my leiningen managed app?

Tags: clojure

Goes without saying that I'm new to clojure. As a learning project, I'd like to use the [caldav4j](https://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/) library to pull down work calendar events however I don't know how to properly pull in an external library that is not found via "lein search".

**Update**: Sharing my working project.clj file for reference:

```
(defproject caldav-sync "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Extract and synchronize calendar entries locally"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.osaf/caldav4j "0.7"]]
  :repositories [["caldav4j" "https://caldav4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven/"]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the dependency section of the leiningen tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#dependencies). You would add the groupid/artifactid (probably `org.osaf/caldav4j`) as a dependency in the `:dependencies` vector. Apparently, caldav4j isn't available on Maven central according to its [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/wiki/FAQ), so you'll need to add the Maven repository mentioned in the FAQ via the `:repositories` key.